# Puppet 3.6.2 breaks Puppetlabs Apache on CentOS 6.5 on first run, installs on second run

Tags: apache, puppet, centos6, yum

I'm using a CentOS 6.5 box that comes with Puppet 3.4.0. I have the necessary dependencies, stdlib and concat. Here's the code I'm using to install the Apache module:

```
class { 'apache':
  default_mods        => false,
  default_confd_files => false,
}
```

This runs fine on 3.4.0. However, when I run yum update like so:

```
exec { "yum_update":
  command => "yum -y update",
  path    => "/usr/bin",
  timeout => 0,
  before => Package["httpd"] 
}
```

It installs puppet 3.6.2, and I get a ton of errors and Apache doesn't get installed...

```
Stderr from the command:

Warning: Config file /vagrant/hiera.yamlm not found, using Hiera defaults
Error: /Stage[main]/Concat::Setup/File[/var/lib/puppet/concat/bin/concatfragments.sh]: Could not evaluate: undefined method `exist?' for Puppet::FileSystem:Module Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///modules/concat/concatfragments.sh: undefined method `exist?' for Puppet::FileSystem:Module
Error: Could not back up /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Unsupported checksum type "md5"
Error: Could not back up /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Unsupported checksum type "md5"
Error: /Stage[main]/Apache/File[/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf]/content: change from {md5}27a5c8d9e75351b08b8ca1171e8a0bbd to {md5}87926a96450a8af968c3b0c9675b373c failed: Could not back up /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Unsupported checksum type "md5"
Error: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]/File[/var/lib/puppet/concat/_etc_httpd_conf_ports.conf/fragments]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': undefined method `exist?' for Puppet::FileSystem:Module
Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]/Exec[concat_/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]/Exec[concat_/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]: Failed to call refresh: Could not find command '/var/lib/puppet/concat/bin/concatfragments.sh'
Error: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]/Exec[concat_/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]: Could not find command '/var/lib/puppet/concat/bin/concatfragments.sh'
Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache/Concat[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]/File[/etc/httpd/conf/ports.conf]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: /Stage[main]/Apache/File[/etc/httpd/conf.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': undefined method `exist?' for Puppet::FileSystem:Module
Warning: /Stage[main]/Apache::Service/Service[httpd]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: Report processor failed: undefined method `exist?' for Puppet::FileSystem:Module
```

...the first time. Running `vagrant provision` again results in only deprecation warnings and apache gets installed is running when I ssh in.

I know the hiera thing isn't a big deal, although I put `--hiera_config /vagrant/hiera.yamlm` in my Vagrant file so I'm not sure why it's still there.

I tried Googling a lot of these errors and I've seen some bug reports, but nothing seems to address this directly. When I see a ton of errors like this I usually think missing dependencies, but I can't figure out what I could be missing here. Thanks so much in advance for any help!

Comment: This happens in `vagrant`? Is there a Puppet master involved?

Comment: Nope - I'm just getting started with Vagrant/Puppet and running everything locally on my machine. The box I'm using is http://www.lyricalsoftware.com/downloads/centos65.box

Answer (score 1):

Updating Puppet from within Puppet is fine, but don't expect the same agent process to do anything useful after the fact.

For the background process, this usually entails a service restart, and if run by cron, you get a new agent process on the next interval.

Doing the version upgrade during (an early phase of) provisioning sounds like a Bad Idea.

Perhaps you can run `yum update` before Puppet, independently?

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I'm thinking of running the update as the very last task.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge i can help you to some extent.
here u can go with this puppet manifest for apache2(httpd) in centos.

In your manifests folder create 2 .pp files (init.pp,install.pp)
open init.pp file with nano,vi or vim...and write below in init.pp

```
class httpd {
    include httpd::install
}
```

After that open install.pp file and write below script.

```
class httpd::install {
    package { 'httpd':
        ensure => installed,
    }

    service { 'httpd':   
        ensure => running,
        hasrestart => true,
        hasstatus  => true,
        require    => Package['httpd'],
    }

   exec { "yum_update" :
       command => "yum update",
       path    => "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin",
       timeout => 180,
       before => Package['httpd'], 
   }
```

Run this in site.pp following:

```
node 'ur node here with fqdn' 
{   
    include httpd
}
```

run with `puppet agent --test`.